# How do I add an option to a select box in a parent window using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my child window I have

```
$('#opfile').addOption("someval",sometext");
```

Problem is #opfile is an a parent window I cant get it to communicate

I tried

window.opener.$('#opfile').addOption("someval",sometext");

but no luck any ideas?

Update

Embarssing but I got the above to work might have been caching something

Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be helpful.

[Communication between browser windows](http://www.sfpeter.com/2008/03/13/communication-between-browser-windows-with-jquery-my-new-plugin/)

Though this is not directly related to the select box example, but the concepts may be applied here.

I'll watch this space, if anyone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this by changing array in options

window.opener.document.getElementById("opfile").options[0] = new Option("someval",sometext");